# pushing documents to manager's phone

Tags: cloud, documents

I want my senior managers to be able to open files on their phones, in either PDF or DOC.  The format is not really the problem.  But they are not too IT savvy.  They just want ot push a button on their phone to open an app and have a library of files there. They don't understand dropbox....

I have 2 apps on my own android phone, both religious, that contain a long list of prayers or books (e.g. the bible).  Every now and then each of these is updated automatically with new prayers or hymns or whatever.  A similar idea would be a list of recipes, which is updated automatically each time  a new recipe is available.

Is there a way that would enable my managers to open a library of files, which would update automatically with new files or newer verions of existing files whenever a new file was available? That way they don't have to 'dock' their phones, or ring up to have a file sent to them -- but the files would be automatically 'pushed' from a central site to a selected list of users.
Sounds simple to me. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: I know you mentioned that they don't understand Dropbox, but that's exactly what you're describing. If not Dropbox, does a solution like Google Docs work?

Comment: Google Drive ftw...

Comment: Seems off topic as it is seeking recommendation, which according to the FAQ "Recommendations, like "Which phone is better?" or "Can you suggest an app that does X?"" are off topic.

Comment: @ZnewmaN it can be re-phrased to "How can I do this". Forgive a first-timer the wording. I will edit the question to make it on-topic ;)

Comment: @Izzy you're right. My bad. Just seemed like it when breezing over.

Comment: No problem -- this very same thing confused me often enough. @Tom: Check my re-phrasing -- it should not have changed the idea behind it. Please forgive us that we sometimes "jump" at certain keywords/phrasings :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the playstore. While the "official" Dropbox app might be too much for them (forgive them, they are just managers), there are others where you can define folders to be automatically synchronized. Take e.g. a look at [Dropsync](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/market/apps/app/com.ttxapps.dropsync/Dropsync) or [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite). Create a Dropbox account to share for this purpose, and configure that on all affected devices -- and your problem should be solved.